# minimum and maximum value of 2-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you find min,max values of $f(x,y)=xye^{xy-4y}$ when $-4\le x \le 1$ and when $-1\le y \le 4$.

min and max when $x=-4$ and $-1\le y \le 4$

or when $x=1$ and $-1\le y \le 4$

and the global min max.

EDIT: Yeah how can I find the min/max along the edges of this rectangle and the global ones.

Comment: Maybe the directions of the inequalities should be changed to $-4 \le x \le 1$ and $-1 \le y \le 4.$ Also I'd drop the term "cube" and just ask about max/min of $f(x,y).$

Comment: There are still the reversed inequalities after the first sentence. Also make clear-- are you just looking for global min and max, or also to find any local min/max of the function? [There may be local min/max along some edges of the rectangle of your inequality restrictions.]

Comment: OK got it. Note there are the two other edges when $y=-1$ and $-4 \le x \le 1$ and $y=4$ and $-4 \le x \le 1.$ The basic idea is that one find any critical points of $f$ in the interior and look near them, and then do each edge separately as a one variable max/min problem. There is only one critical point interior at $(0,0)$ which can be seen by taking the two partials of $f$ and setting both to zero simultaneously. And $(0,0)$ is neither a local max or local min by looking at its sign in the four quadrants near the origin.

Answer (score 0):

By writing this function as $ \ f(x, \ y) \ = \ xy \ e^{(x-4) \ y} \ = \ xy \ \cdot \ e^{xy} \ \cdot \ e^{-4y} \ $ , there is a fair amount we can say, from our knowledge of exponential functions, about its behavior on the specified square before we resort to the use of calculus.

Since $ \ x \ < \ 4 \ $ everywhere in the region, the exponential factor $ \ e^{(x-4) \ y} \ $ is driven rapidly to zero for increasingly positive values of  $ \ y \ $ , and the factor increases rapidly in the negative-$  y \ $ direction.  This factor also decreases generally toward zero "from right to left" across the square.  For this factor alone then, we would expect the absolute minimum to occur on the $ \ y \ = \ 4 \ $ edge of the square, the absolute maximum, on the $ \ y \ = \ -1 \ $ edge, and both extrema to be found on the $ \ x \ = \ -4 \ $ edge.  This would place the absolute maximum at $ \ ( -4, \ -1) \ $ and the absolute minimum at $ \ ( -4, \ 4) \ $ .

This is also, however, the factor $ \ xy \ $ to contend with, which has the effect of making our function *negative* in the second and fourth quadrant; this factor is also larger for points farther away from the origin.  Since $ \ (-4, \ -1) \ $ is in the third quadrant, it likely remains the absolute maximum for this region.  However, the value of the function at $ \ ( -4, \ 4) \ $ in the second quadrant becomes a negative number close to zero, while the value at $ \ ( 1, \ -1) \ $ in the fourth quadrant may now turn out to be a *more negative* number.

From our experience in single-variable calculus with functions such as $ \ x \ e^{-x} \ $ , we may expect that there are relative extrema within the region for small values of $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ . We also easily see that the function is zero along both coordinate axes.

$ \ $

So saying, we will next look at what differentiation of the function tells us.  The first partial derivatives are

$$ f_x \ = \ y \ (1 \ + \ xy) \ e^{xy} \ \cdot \ e^{-4y} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ f_y \ = \ x \ (1 \ + \ xy \ - \ 4y) \ e^{xy} \ \cdot \ e^{-4y} \ \ . $$

Since the exponential factors can only be positive, we have $ \ f_x \ = \ 0 \ $ on $ \ y \ = \ 0 \ $ or the curve $ \ y \ = \ -\frac{1}{x} \ $ , and $ \ f_y \ = \ 0 \ $ on $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ or the curve $ \ y \ = \ -\frac{1}{x - 4} \ $ .  The only intersection point among these is at the origin, as the two relatively "horizontally-shifted" hyperbolas never intersect; hence, this is the sole critical point.  (Much of this is already suggested in **coffeemath**'s comments.)

We have already seen that the function is zero at the origin; while we could compute the second partial derivatives there, it is not hard to see that because the exponential factors are both very close to one near the origin, the function behaves essentially like $ z \ = \ xy \ $ there, which makes this a saddle point ("upward" concavity along $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , "downward" along $ \ y \ = \ -x \ $ ) .

[image]

*The region of interest is the gold-filled square; the two hyperbolas described above are marked in pale blue and pale green.*

We will next wish to study the function along the edges of the square:

**for *x* = 1 --**  $ \ \ f(1, \ y) \ = \ y \ e^{-3y} \ \ : \ \  f \ ' \ = \ (1 \ - \ 3y) \ e^{-3y} \ \ , \ \ f \ '' \ = \ (9y \ - \ 6) \ e^{-3y} $

$ \quad \quad \Rightarrow \ \ $ relative maximum $ \ f(1, \ \frac{1}{3}) \ = \ \frac{1}{3e} \ \ ; $

**for *y* = -1 --**  $ \ \ f(x, \ -1) \ = \ -e^4 \ x \ e^{-x} \ \ : \ \  f \ ' \ = \ e^4 \ (x \ - \ 1) \ e^{-x} \ \ , \ \ f \ '' \ = \ e^4 \ (2 \ - \ x) \ e^{-x} $

$ \quad \quad \Rightarrow \ \ $ relative minimum $ \ f(1, \ -1) \ = \ -e^3 \ \ ; $

**for *y* = 4 --**  $ \ \ f(x, \ 4) \ = \ 4e^{-16} \ x \ e^{4x} \ \ : \ \  f \ ' \ = \ 4e^{-16} \ (1 \ + \ 4x) \ e^{4x} \ \ , \ \ f \ '' \ = \ 4e^{-16} \ (16x \ + \ 8) \ e^{4x} $

$ \quad \quad \Rightarrow \ \ $ relative minimum $ \ f(-\frac{1}{4}, \ 4) \ = \ -e^{-17} \ \ ;  \ \ $ and

**for *x* = -4 --**  $ \ \ f(-4, \ y) \ = \ -4 \ y \ e^{-8y} \ \ : \ \  f \ ' \ = \ -4 \ (1 \ - \ 8y) \ e^{-8y} \ \ , \ \ f \ '' \ = \ -4 \ (64y \ - \ 16) \ e^{-8y} $

$ \quad \quad \Rightarrow \ \ $ relative minimum $ \ f(-4, \ \frac{1}{8}) \ = \ -\frac{1}{2e} \ \ . $

We have evaluated the function at one of its vertices, $ \ (1, \ -1 ) \ $ and found its value to be a moderately large negative number ( $ \ \approx \ -20 \ $ ) .  At the remaining vertices, we obtain

$$ f( 1, \ 4) \ = \ 4 \ e^{-12} \ \ , \ \ f( -4, \ 4) \ = \ -16 \ e^{-32} \ \ , \ \ f( -4, \ -1) \ = \ 4 \ e^8 \ \approx \ 11,924 \ \ . $$

Thus, our initial surmises about this function over the specified square are confirmed: the **absolute minimum** occurs at $ \ (1, \ -1) \ $ and the **absolute maximum** at $ \ ( -4, \ -1) \ $ .